# How to remap ALT(left) and WIN(left) key for a logitech keyboard on a notebook?

Tags: keyboard, remapping, logitech-keyboard

I have a notebook and I am using logitech mx keys for mac.

So I want to only switch the <kbd>ALT</kbd> and <kbd>WIN</kbd> key on that logitech keyboard.

I have tried the app PowerToy. It switches my notebook keyboard as well.

Is there a way I remap the keys specifically on the external logitech keyboard only?

Comment: Hardware workaround: If the key tops are the same size, pop off the tops and switch them.

Comment: @DrMoishe I'm not sure if that's what is meant. To change the layout for only one of your two keyboards in Windows, you could consider https://www.autohotkey.com/